# How to output the outcome into a string variable - what goes wrong here?

Tags: php, string, variables

I'm having trouble with setting a variable and then giving it the outcome of a translated string. What am I doing wrong?

```
# usage: this translates some text into different language.
echo __('some text'); 

# make a variable and fill it with the outcome of the translated text
$title="echo __('translated content text')";
```

The first line outputs nicely.
The second line output literaly `echo __('translated concent text')`.

## Update

Thanks all. great answers. Gosh how stupid i must ve been, therefore am a bit wiser now:)

```
$title = __('Colourful train rides');   # works
```

now experimenting with these endings
`ob_end_flush();`
`ob_end_clean();`

Comment: Does `__echo` directly output data or return a string?

Comment: A more common idiom is to separate the translating and output functionality. It's preferrable to use something like `echo t('orig text')` with `t()` or `_()` being the most common names for such functions. `__echo()` seems a bit misnamed.

Comment: Mario, thanks for insights. My fault. Does function echo __(''); sound better named? cause thats the working funciton wich is, obviously, not written by me,  I WISHED!! :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't include quotes around the function call and don't call `echo`:

```
$title = __('translated concent text');
```

Comment: completely right Mark! gosh my dyslectia lets me down so often. its used like `echo __('');` (changed my question.

Comment: @Sam: OK, no problem! I've updated my answer based on your updated question.

Comment: Thanks Mark! Works beautifully now. Will take a dive into that flush(send) and clean(erase) once i truly understand whats the similarity/differences. Cheers!

Comment: @Sam: I think you don't need the ob_* calls here.

Answer (score 5):

> The first line outputs nicely

It sounds like that function echoes (also, its name would be very confusing if it didn't).

You will need to use an output buffer to capture that output.

```
ob_start();
__echo('translated concent text');
$title = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean(); // Thanks BoltClock
```

Comment: Hi Alex, whats the difference between `ob_end_flush();`, and `ob_end_clean();` ?

Comment: @Sam [`ob_end_flush()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php) & [`ob_end_clean()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php).

Comment: @Sam: `ob_end_flush()` echoes everything in the output buffer, while `ob_end_clean()` discards it (unless you assign it to a variable)

Answer (score 2):

You're wrapping the function call in quotes, so it's being outputted literally (instead of invoking the function). Take away the pair of quotes, and you'll have a result closer to what you want:

```
$title = __echo('translated concent text');
```

However, for this to work the **__echo()** function will have to *return* the string, not just echo it. If you want to catch the output, you'll have to use PHP's [Output Buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php).

```
ob_start();
__echo('translated concent text');
$title = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: Hi Jamie, is the ooutbut buffering done for persormance boost only, or for another reason(s)?